# Significantly different LAN transmit speed

Tags: performance, http, tcp, lan

I have two machines, one Mac and one Linux, in the same local network. I tried to transfer files by using one of them as an HTTP server, it turned out the download speeds were quite different based on which one was the server. If I use Mac as the server, the download speed was around 3MB/s, but in the opposite way, it's about 12MB/s. Then I used `iperf3` to test the speed between them and got a similar result:

When Mac was the server and Linux the client:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bitrate         Retr
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  28.7 MBytes  2942 KBytes/sec  1905             sender
[  5]   0.00-10.00  sec  28.4 MBytes  2913 KBytes/sec                  receiver
```

When Linux was the server and Mac the client:

```
[ ID] Interval           Transfer     Bandwidth        
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  162 MBytes  16572 KBytes/sec                  sender
[  4]   0.00-10.00  sec  161 MBytes  16526 KBytes/sec                  receiver
```

I asked a friend to do the download test for me and he told me the speeds were both around 1MB/s on his two Mac, which was far from the router's capacity. How could this happen?

Comment: Packet loss.  "Retr" is showing you the number of retransmitted segments. https://github.com/esnet/iperf/issues/343

Comment: Just to quantify it, 28.7 MB / (1500 bytes / segment) ~= 19,000 segments.  The 1905 retransmitted segments implies a packet loss rate of ~10% which will have a huge impact on TCP throughput even with a RTT of 0 ms.

Comment: @JimD. Thanks for the reply, it's really helpful. But why the packet loss always happen in one direction but not the other?

Comment: No idea.  Tell us more about your LAN.  Wireless or Wired? Cable types or WIFI band....

Comment: @JimD. OK, so it's not a general problem. I will try to explore what's wrong with my network as I thought it's a very simple one, just two machines connect to a router through wifi. Really appreciate your help!

Comment: I might suggest trying it wired to see what happens, as I'm guessing the Mac and maybe also the linux machine were wireless.  You can get inexpensive USB network adapters.

Comment: Sure, will try it.

Comment: I was thinking too hard.  Simple (and free) thing to do first is to ping your router from both the mac and linux box and see if you see any packet loss or difference in packet loss.  Specify `-s 1458` to send a full 1500 byte MTU.

Comment: Thanks for your interest. The ping results from both machines to the router are fine without packet loss. I used Wireshark to capture the packets when using iperf3, and the captured result has many [TCP window update] as well as [bogus TCP header length] frames, and of course, [TCP Retrasmission]. And these errors only happen in one direction. I also tried to increase the TCP buffer size of MacOS, but no luck.

Answer (score 0):

This isn't going to be much of an answer, but it will probably be long enough that it is not going to fit into a comment.

Your observation of "bogus TCP header length" is very interesting; I have never seen it in a capture before, so I wanted to check out exactly what it means.  [Here](https://github.com/wireshark/wireshark/blob/1d7bc367e943464f912a67ad436fabddb1a61a37/epan/dissectors/packet-tcp.c#L6443) you can see that it means that the wireshark TCP protocol dissector can't make any sense of the segment, because the TCP header length is less than the minimum TCP header length.

So it seems you have an invalid TCP segment.  Only two causes I know are that it was somehow erroneously constructed (i.e. a bug or intrusion attempt) or that it was corrupted.

I have certainly created plenty of invalid segments when working with raw sockets, and I have seen plenty of forged segments that were not standards conforming, but this doesn't seem likely to be the case in your situation.

So, based on my experience, it seems most likely that it has been somehow corrupted.  Although if it was a transmitted packet in the capture, then you are actually sending a invalid segment.  So in what follows, I'm assuming it was a received segment.

So where could it have been corrupted?  The first mystery is that you are seeing it at all in a capture.  If it had been corrupted in the network, the Frame Check Sequence (FCS, a CRC) shouldn't match, and it should have been discarded.

However, it is possible to configure your NIC/Driver to deliver segments with an invalid FCS.  On linux you would check/configure these settings with `ethtool` and the relevant parameters are `rx-fcs` and `rx-all` (sorry, I don't know how to do this on a Mac).  If those are both "off," your NIC/Driver should not be sending you segments with an invalid FCS and hence they wouldn't appear in a capture.

Since you are seeing the segments with an invalid TCP header length in your capture, and assuming your NIC/Driver is configured to drop segments with an invalid FCS, then your NIC saw a valid segment on the wire, and the segment was either corrupted before the FCS was calculated by a transmitter (usually done in the NIC), or corrupted after the FCS was validated by the receiving NIC.

In both these cases, there is a DMA transfer over a bus (e.g. PCI-e) between CPU memory and the NIC.  I'm guessing there is a hardware problem causing corruption here, but I'm not so confident in this guess as I have little information to go on.

You might try getting a capture on both ends to compare what is transmitted to what is received (particularly in the case of segments with invalid TCP header lengths).  You can match segments in the captures using the ID field in the IP header (assuming that doesn't get corrupted as well).

Good luck figuring it out!